# is converting json to Neo4j a good idea?

Tags: json, neo4j

I want to crawl web for some users information and then store the obtained data in a graph database.

I have been suggested to first store the obtained data as json and then convert json to Neo4j graph database.

Is that a good idea? why ?

Comment: If you crawl the web, you will come across a lot of semistructured, highly interconnected data. Graph databases are a very good fit for this sort of use case. Whether or not you use JSON as an intermediate representation depends on your toolchain -- Neo4j has excellent support for loading JSONs.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the data. If you can easily and directly convert the data into the graph information that you need go ahead and do that. If you are not sure and don't want to crawl for the information repeatedly, store the obtained data in another datastore, and selectively pull in the information into your graph model